# workaround of lassign [chan pipe] for TCL8.5

Tags: pipe, tcl

I need to use "chan pipe" but my TCL Version is 8.5 and I can't use 8.6.
Here is my code in 8.6

```
lassign [chan pipe] read_pipe write_pipe
puts $write_pipe "AAA"
close $write_pipe

puts $read_pipe
```

Can you suggest any workaround?

http://wiki.tcl.tk/21521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TEA-based extension out of this implementation called `tclpipe` is available. It can be used with (supposedly) any version of Tcl (tested on 8.4 and 8.5).

```
package require pipe
lassign [pipe] readChanId writeChanId
...
close $readChanId; close $writeChanId
```

This extension provides one `Tcl` command, `pipe`, created in the root namespace.
The code is taken from the implementation of the `chan pipe` command with the purpose of making this functionality available for `Tcl` versions <= 8.5 while not requiring the presence of the `Tclx` package. The syntax and semantics of the provided command are the same as of `chan pipe`, just the name differs.

The source and Win32 binary (built using the MSVC 6.0 compiler) are hosted [here](http://sgolovan.nes.ru/jabber/tclpipe/).
The source is confirmed to build and work on Windows XP (MSYS/MinGW and MSVC 6.0) and Debian Linux ("Etch").

Source : http://wiki.tcl.tk/21637

Comment: Thanks, 
I found this wiki already.
Trying to install the lib pipe.
Thanks you again.